# why does the pumping lemma want us to only consider the first repitition of states?

Tags: computability, automata, finite-automata, computation-models

In Sipser's Intro to Theory and computation, He writes: [image]

I don't understand the constraint on x. Shouldn't it be just y <=p? (Equal bc in the case when machine M runs through all states p) Making xy <=p, the theorem only wants us to consider the first p elements and the first repetiton. Why can't any repetition be considered for the pumping lemma? We can simply pick an arbitrary substring of length p and the looping structure works just fine? 
Is this constraint on x just to generalize since some inputs may not have more than one looping structure?

Comment: This additional constraint works in your favor. You’re free to ignore it.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!